# Regex: Start of string does not behave as expected

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing (by regex) a .map file generated by a linker for ARM. I have extracted pretty much everything but this section is resisting.

Here is an excerpt of the part I want to parse

```
COMMON         0x20002b18        0x1 ./2_Programa/source/board.o
               0x20002b18                BOARD_ctx
COMMON         0x20002b19       0x87 ./2_Programa/source/interface_objects.o
               0x20002b19                GLB_appIntObjPropChangeFlags
               0x20002b1a                GLB_aioBLCommand
               0x20002b65                GLB_aioDateTime
COMMON         0x20002ba0       0x31 ./2_Programa/source/objects.o
               0x20002ba0                GLB_goFlags
*fill*         0x20002bd1        0x3
```

and this is my best regex attempt:

```
^ COMMON\s+(0x\S+)\s+(0x\S+).*(?:\s+(0x\S+)\s+(\S+)[\r\n])*(?:\s+\*fill\*\s+0x\S+\s+(0x\S+))?
```

The result can be checked [here](https://regex101.com/r/O6Vc6C/1/). The result I get, only matches the last line of the block (I consider a block when it starts with `COMMON`).

What I need to extract is something similar to this:

```
[{
    'name': 'GLB_appIntObjPropChangeFlags',
    'size': 0x01,
    'path': './2_Programa/source/interface_objects.o',
    'origin': 0x20002b19
},
{
    'name': 'GLB_aioBLCommand',
    'size': 0x87,
    'path': './2_Programa/source/interface_objects.o',
    'origin': 0x20002b1a
},
...
]
```

My main problem here is that I am not able to separate the first line

```
COMMON 0x20002b19 0x87 ./2_Programa/source/interface_objects.o`
```

from the others related to it

```
        0x20002b19                GLB_appIntObjPropChangeFlags
        0x20002b1a                GLB_aioBLCommand
        0x20002b65                GLB_aioDateTime
```

Could anyone give some hints to face this off?

**UPDATE**

What I would like to do is to split all blocks (those that start with `COMMON`) into two parts. Group 1:

```
COMMON 0x20002b19 0x87 ./2_Programa/source/interface_objects.o`
```

and Group2:

```
        0x20002b19                GLB_appIntObjPropChangeFlags
        0x20002b1a                GLB_aioBLCommand
        0x20002b65                GLB_aioDateTime
```

Then, I could regex each group separately:

Regex for Group 1:

```
^ COMMON\s+(0x\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)
```

and this other for Group 2 (setting multi line flag):

```
^\s+(0x\S+)\s+(\S+)
```

As a result I will get three groups from first regex and other six (2 per line per 3 lines) which could easily converted in a list of `dict`s as I showed above.

Comment: How does your expected output associate `0x01` with `GLB_appIntObjPropChangeFlags`?

Comment: the expected output is unclear. Some relations look arbitrary

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/r/O6Vc6C/2 to get each block. Parse as you need later.

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

Realistically, you should grab each `COMMON` block as mentioned in the comments under your question by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew). Link to Wiktor's regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/O6Vc6C/2). Regex does not have the ability to loop over a subquery (that's not its purpose).

Impractically, you can use this regex to grab each `COMMON` section and its following blocks, and then map it.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/XkQN5x/5)

```
(?:COMMON\s+0x[0-9a-f]+\s+(0x[0-9a-f]+)\s+(\S+)|\s*(0x[0-9a-f]+)\s+(\S+))(?=\s*[\r\n])
```

---

### Explanation

- `COMMON\s+0x[0-9a-f]+\s+(0x[0-9a-f]+)\s+(\S+)` Option 1

  - `COMMON\s+0x[0-9a-f]+\s+`

    - `COMMON` The characters `COMMON` literally
    - `\s+` One or more whitespace characters
    - `0x` These characters `0x` literally
    - `[0-9a-f]+` One or more of the characters in the set `0-9a-f`
    - `\s+` One or more whitespace characters `\s+`
  - `(0x[0-9a-f]+)` Capture the following into capture group 1

    - `0x` These characters `0x` literally
    - `[0-9a-f]+` One or more of the characters in the set `0-9a-f`
  - `\s+` One or more whitespace characters
  - `(\S+)` Capture one or more non-whitespace characters into capture group 2
- `\s*(0x[0-9a-f]+)\s+(\S+)` Option 2

  - `\s*` Any number of whitespace characters
  - `(0x[0-9a-f]+)` Capture the following into capture group 3

    - `0x` These characters `0x` literally
    - `[0-9a-f]+` One or more of the characters in the set `0-9a-f`
  - `\s+` One or more whitespace characters
  - `(\S+)` Capture one or more non-whitespace characters into capture group 4
- `(?=\s*[\r\n])` Ensure what follows is any number of whitespace characters, followed by a newline character `\r\n`

---

### Usage

Based on the order of the matches and the groups to which they belong, you can map them to an array as you've presented.

For example (in match order).

- First set

  - **Group 1** `0x1`
  - **Group 2** `./2_Programa/source/board.o`
  - Group 3 `0x20002b18`
  - Group 4`BOARD_ctx`
- Second set

  - **Group 1** `0x87`
  - **Group 2** `./2_Programa/source/interface_objects.o`
  - Group 3 `0x20002b19`
  - Group 4 `GLB_appIntObjPropChangeFlags`
  - Group 3 `0x20002b1a`
  - Group 4 `GLB_aioBLCommand`
  - Group 3 `0x20002b65`
  - Group 4 `GLB_aioDateTime`
- etc.

Always associating the last match for group 1 and group 2 to the current match for group 3 and group 4

Comment: Although your explanation is complete and really explanatory (thanks, I have learned quite a lot with this question) I do also need to match the `*fill*` text so [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)'s solution (with couple of tweaks) fits better my needs.

Comment: @WoozyCoder it's the better answer, I just thought I would provide an alternative that might also work (2 options are better than 1 - assuming they work that is)

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me. I asure you I've learned quite a lot with your answer, specially facing the problem from another point of view.